# リポジトリをコピーするには

Tags: centos, yum

CentOSを使っています。
リポジトリを登録するのですが、よくリポジトリが無くなったり変更されたりします。
そのためリポジトリをコピーして、削除されても使えるようにしたいと思っています。

そこで質問ですが、
(1) リポジトリをコピーする方法（1つずつrpmをダウンロードするしかないのか？）
(2) コピーしたリポジトリをhttpdサーバに配置すれば、リポジトリの向き先を変えるだけで使えるのか。
(3) そもそも(1)(2)のようなことしなくても、ローカルにリポジトリ領域を保存できるなど便利な方法があるか。
をご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

公開リポジトリからパッケージを一括でダウンロードするには、`rsync`や`lftp`などでミラーリングする方法もありますが、yumリポジトリのミラーリングを目的とした`reposync`というコマンドがCentOS/RHELには用意されています。

`reposync`コマンドは`yum-utils`パッケージに含まれています。また、独自のリポジトリを作成するには`createrepo`コマンドも必要になるのでそれぞれインストールしておいてください。

```
$ sudo yum install yum-utils createrepo -y
```

パッケージのミラーリングと(createrepoで)メタデータの作成を済ませたら、httpdを含め適当な方法でリポジトリを参照可能な状態にしてやればOKです。

なお、リポジトリの参照先として`/etc/yum.repo.d/`以下の`*.repo`ファイルに記述する必要がありますが、既存のファイルとは別に用意した方が管理しやすいと思います。

参考：
[独自/ミラー yum リポジトリを作ろう](http://blog.asial.co.jp/681)
[CentOSのローカルyumリポジトリの作り方](https://blog.u6k.me/2013/06/20/build-local-yum-repository-for-centos.html)